# Pyspark - Unable to read the data from AWS S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am trying to read data from S3 bucket using Pyspark on Jupyterhub using the code below

```
config = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([("spark.executor.instances", "4")\
,('spark.executor.memory', '50g')\
, ('spark.executor.cores', '4')\
, ('spark.cores.max', '48')\
, ('spark.driver.memory','50g')\
, ("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "35g")                             
, ("spark.jars", "/home/aws_jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar,/home/aws_jars/aws-java-sdk-1.11.30.jar")])

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=config).getOrCreate()

# connect to AWS with boto3
sess = boto3.Session(region_name='us-east-1')
credentials = sess.get_credentials()
credentials = credentials.get_frozen_credentials()

sc=spark.sparkContext
hadoop_conf=sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()

hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", credentials.access_key)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", credentials.secret_key)

df = spark.read.load('s3a://ml-bucket/spark-project/data/D2021117_BI_1982.txt',format ="csv",inferSchema="true")
df.show()
```

Here is the exception that I got.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o63.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException
```

Here are the versions on the server

```
Hadoop 2.7.3
Python 3.6.12
Spark Version 3.1.2
openjdk version 1.8.0_312
```

I tried troubleshooting it with different hadoop-aws and aws-jdk versions. But, I am not able to make it work. I am also able to read it using Pandas but not with Pysaprk. Am I missing something here?

**Update**

Here is the complete error log after I replaced aws-java-sdk-1.11.30 with aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.901

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o59.load.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `aws-java-sdk-bundle`. It has SDK all the classes for AWS services.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle

Note: `aws-java-sdk` (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.12.126)  actually doesn't have any java class (if you extract you will find out). It has all the was java SDK classes as dependencies so you need to compile to get all the dependencies. Alternatively, you can directly download the `aws-java-sdk-bundle` mentioned above and you are good to go.

Comment: Any idea on the matching version number?

Comment: I tried with 1.12.3. But, I still got Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o64.load.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1314)

Comment: Can you share the complete error log ?

Comment: you tried the complete 200 MB bundle right?

Comment: Which version of spark are you using ?

Comment: Yes, I used the bundle. Spark version is 3.1.2. I just updated the question with full log

Comment: Looks like a progress, try removing `inferSchema` args and then use load.

Comment: Tried. Still the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some jars to be provided in your spark application

> spark-submit --jars
> [aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.128.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.12.128), [hadoop-aws-3.2.2.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws) ...

For [aws-java-sdk](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.12.128) you don't need the whole AWS services just the S3 service.

For [hadoop-aws](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws) you need to know which version of Hadoop you're using with spark.